# WordPress Plugin Localization

Tags: wordpress, plugins, localization

I've just built my first plugin for WordPress, and even if it's not a great "code poetry" it works as it should. It's a plugin that transform the default wp gallery using the GalleryView 3.0 jQuery plugin (http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview).

The only thing I'm not able to do is localization.
Localization for this plugin in means translating the admin interface, where someone can configure the jQuery plugin options to change the aspect of the resulting gallery.

I've tried to follow the millions of tutorials present on the web, read a lot of posts about this issue on forums and followed the guidelinees of codex... but still with no luck.

this is what I've done:

1. every text line is inside a gettext function ( `__` and `_e` )
2. using poedit I created the .po and .mo file scanning the plugin directory (everything went ok), then i added translations on that file.
3. I named the .po file like that NAME-OF-THE-PLUGIN-it_IT.po (the .mo file was generated with the same name)
4. I've put the translations files inside the plugin folder/languages (name of the folder is the same of the plugin and of the translations files)
5. then I've tried to add the `load_plugin_textdomain` function inside the main plugin file. I've tried because there's no way to get it working.

The only thing on which I'm not sure is the fact that the plugin I've created is not under a class+constructor functions... just because I'm still not so good in coding.

But I've put the `load_plugin_textdomain` inside an `init add_action`, like this:

```
add_action('init', 'gw_load_translation_file');

function gw_load_translation_file() {
// relative path to WP_PLUGIN_DIR where the translation files will sit:
$plugin_path = dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) .'/languages' );
load_plugin_textdomain( 'gallery-view-for-wordpress', false, $plugin_path );
}
```

the lines above are not inside a logic, they are just in the main plugin file, like that.

this is an example of my use of gettext functions:

```
<h3><?php _e('Panel Options','gallery-view-for-wordpress') ?></h3>
```

What did I not understand?

Comment: What language is set in your wp-config.php ?

Comment: I am also having issues with this. Have so far failed to find anything helpful on google - perhaps a new issue with the most recent versions of WP? Seems a bit odd that it'd only affect plugins, though. The only difference between my attempts and the OP's is that I'm trying to load .mo and .po files from the /plugins root dir (the same location as the actual plugin.php file). My wplang is set to fr-FR - the current theme is fine, it's just the plugin that won't load the text domain.

Comment: @hollsk, i've posted the question even here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/plugin-localization but no luck, someone says it's working... but not for me

Comment: For me it works, and I even tried it on serbian, changing files to sr_RS lang. :) Here is SS: http://efekat.com/public/images/Gallery%20View%20for%20Wordpress%20Settings%20%E2%80%B9%20Adi%C5%BEes%20SEE%20%E2%80%94%20Vordpres%20-%20Chromium_001.png I know this is kind a stupid question, but how do you install your plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mistake was on language files path declaration.

this fixed:

```
$plugin_path = dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/';
```

this was wrong:

```
$plugin_path = dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) .'/languages' );
```

I was answered on [Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/plugin-localization/12909#12909)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is the most annoying debugging moment I've ever had, since learning that blank lines at the end of .PHP files are not meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to my previous statement, I've succeeded using this filename: `gallery-view-for-wp-it_IT.mo`

Strange, though - themes use just `it_IT.mo`.

Comment: @bluantinoo I've managed to get Opzioni Gallery View for Wordpress :) See the edit of the answer.

Comment: @Nikolay do you mean that if you go in the gallery settings page you see the interface translated in italian?

Comment: Just the title, you haven't translated the other fields.

Comment: This hasn't helped with mine which is already using the plugin-name-fr_FR format... here's a zip of my own code that's failing to work, stripped down to the absolute basics and taken from a plugin that was already operational on a different installation of WP: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8907108/i18n-test.zip Any help much appreciated :-)

Comment: One more thing - I'm running Wordpress 3.1. Assume bluantinoo is also up-to-date? Seriously wondering if this is a version-dependent problem after googling around and seeing so many identical questions with no solutions.

Comment: @hollsk This is you solution: `load_plugin_textdomain('i18n-test', false, dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ )  ));`

Comment: @hollsk, i've installed your plugin, but what should happen if it works? I can't see anything...

Comment: @bluantinoo - the show_i18n_test() function needs to be manually added to a template (it is the most basic example possible ;) ) and it will echo out a string to tell you which language it's currently running in.

Comment: @Nikolay - thanks, but setting the dirname of the translation files explicitly doesn't have any effect either, the string is still in English :(

Comment: Is your WPLANG set to fr_FR? It's in `wp-config.php`. What's your WP version?

Comment: yes, wplang is set to fr_FR (the theme templates are all localised to french fine so there doesn't seem to be a problem with the settings) - the WP version is 3.1.0. The only other difference I think is that I'm using multisite - the FR version is a sub-blog.